# Solutions of $|z+5|=|z-1-i|$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to prove what the following set
$$|z+5|=|z-1-i|$$
is in the complex plane. Intuitively you can see that it is a straight line, since they are the points whose distance from points a and b are equal.

But what is the equation of a line on the complex plane ? How is your shape? I'm having trouble because of the $i.$

Comment: Subtraction is not associative. Expressions like $z-1-i$ are ambiguous. Do you mean $z-(1-i)$ or $(z-1)-i$?

Comment: @Shaun Addition ($+$) and subtraction ($-$) have the same priority and are implicitly left-associative, i.e. $a+b-d+f-g-j = ((((a+b)-d)+f)-g)-j$

Comment: Not just any line... a perpendicular bisector.

Comment: @Shaun.  It's not ambiguous at all.  Every mathematician would interpret it as $(z-1)-i$.  Unless otherwise noted subtract goes left to right ... or, as Kenny Lau put it substraction is left-associative.   But... there a is a *real* advantage to writing it as $|z- (1+i)|$  thus it is clearer that it is the difference of two complex numbers.

Comment: I had that advantage in mind, @fleablood, when I typed my comment above, which I retract; I put it down to lack of sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you know that $z$ is the locus of complex numbers of the form $x + yi$ that are equidistant from $-5$ and $1+i$.  This forms a line that passes through the midpoint $-2 + i/2$, and is perpendicular to the slope of the segment joining the two points, i.e., the slope is the negative reciprocal of $\frac{1 - 0}{1+5} = \frac{1}{6}$, which is $-6$.  So we want a line passing through $(-2, 1/2)$, and slope $-6$, or $$(y - 1/2) = -6(x + 2),$$ or $$y = -6x - \frac{23}{2}.$$  This gives us the parametrization $$z = x -(6x + \tfrac{23}{2})i,$$ for all real $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+bi$ satisfy the given equation, then we have $|a+5+bi|=|a-1+(-b-1)i|$ which comes down to $(a+5)^2+b^2=(a-1)^2+(-b-1)^2$ which you can simplify into a relation between $a$ and $b$ yielding a linear equation

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

From Geometry:

If $w_1$ and $w_2$ are complex numbers, then the locus of solutions to

$$|z - w_1| = |z - w_2|$$

will **precisely** be all complex numbers $z$ such that $z$ is on the 
**perpendicular bisector** between $w_1,$ and $w_2$.

Therefore:

- form the line segment connecting $w_1$ and $w_2$.
- find the midpoint $z_0$ of the line segment.
- construct the line that passes through $z_0$ that is perpendicular to the line
  segment connecting $w_1$ and $w_2$.  This means that the slope of the perpendicular line
  will be the negative reciprocal of the slope of the line segment connecting $w_1$ and $w_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.